# R function prcomp fails with NA's values even though NA's are allowed

Tags: r, pca, na

I am using the function `prcomp` to calculate the first two principal components. However, my data has some NA values and therefore the function throws an error. The na.action defined seems not to work even though it is mentioned in the help file `?prcomp`

Here is my example:

```
d <- data.frame(V1 = sample(1:100, 10), V2 = sample(1:100, 10))

prcomp(d, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)

d$V1[5] <- NA
d$V2[7] <- NA

prcomp(d, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
```

I am using the newest R version 2.15.1 for Mac OS X.

Can anybody see the reason while `prcomp` fails?

Here is my new example:

```
d <- data.frame(V1 = sample(1:100, 10), V2 = sample(1:100, 10))

result <- prcomp(d, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)

result$x

d$V1[5] <- NA

result <- prcomp(~V1+V2, data=d, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)

result$x
```

is it possible to retain row 5 in PC1 and PC2? In my real data set I have of course more than two columns of variables and only some of them are missing and I do not want to lose the remaining information hidden in the other values!

Answer (score 33):

Another solution if you're not willing to use formula interface is

```
prcomp(na.omit(d), center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

which consist of applying `na.omit` directly to the data frame.

Comment: Thanks for your solution as well. I just realised that using na.omit results in less principal components. I just edited my example above.

Answer (score 32):

Yeah, it looks like a "feature" (bug) that `na.action` is completely ignored unless you use the `formula` interface. This has been [brought up before on the R Development list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/na-omit-option-in-prcomp-formula-interface-only-td4373533.html).

I think that this should be documented or flagged as a bug.

Just to be clear, this would work because it accesses the formula interface:

```
prcomp(~V1+V2, data=d, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
```

Comment: Ok fantastic. Thanks for the formula approach!

Comment: I agree that it should be documented (I'm the author of the query on the R development list); the best way to push this forward, if someone wanted to, would be to propose a change to the documentation and submit it to the r-devel list (and/or the R bug tracker).

Comment: in 4.3.1, there is a warning that `na.action` is ignored on the OP's request.