# PCA with NAs produces mismatch between subset and data set

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to PCA some columns in larger data set which contains NAs.  When I remove the NAs it produces a mismatch in the number of items so I cannot use the data set for Label info.  How do I fix this?

```
> ef <- sepData[c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
> autoplot(prcomp(na.omit(ef)), data = sepData, colour = 'species', label = TRUE, label.size = 3)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 27, 24
```

sepData contains the sample names on each row.  When I remove omit NAs I lose the order for some columns.

Comment: maybe interpolate your missing values?

Comment: Related posts: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078291/) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35561)

Answer (score 0):

One very quick and easy way to get around this is by replacing missing values with column (variable) medians. The `zoo` package has a nice function `na.aggregate()` for this. Let's say your matrix is called `mat`.

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(mat, FUN = median)
```

Of course, you should really find out *why* your values are missing in order to impute them most appropriately, especially if there are many of them.

Comment: This wouldn't bias a PCA?

Heh, they're missing because the tissue was destroyed during dissection.  :D